# div на всю высоту родительского блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, scss

Народ, всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста, имеется следующий затуп: верстаю макет, тут есть блок с постами блога. Хочу сделать так, чтобы все посты растягивались по высоте по мере необходимости: допустим в одном из постов, в заголовке, много текста и соседние тянутся, чтобы соответствовать ему по высоте. Но не выходит: div с контентом не растягивается по высоте родителя, а остаётся фиксированным. Подскажите, как вылечить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="post-image">
        <img src="pics/blog/1.jpg" alt="blog post picture">
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
        <div class="post-header">
            <h3>all about headshots inside professional studios</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-info">
            <div class="comments">
                <img src="pics/icons/common/comments.png" alt="comments">
                <span>15 Comments</span>
            </div>
            <div class="date">
                <span>June, 2021</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

```
.blog .posts .post {
  flex: 0 1 32.16%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
}
.blog .posts .post h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: Poppins-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.blog .posts .post-image img {
  display: block;
}
.blog .posts .post-info {
  min-height: 200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 22px 22px 30px 26px;
}
.blog .posts .sub-info {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.blog .posts .sub-info .comments {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: вставляйте впредь скомпилированный код CSS

Comment: хорошо, но зачем?

Comment: для удобства отвечающего, чтобы дать ответ, нужно не только разобрать ваш код, но еще и зачем-то искать компилятор

Comment: к тому же, вы вставляете миксины, содержимое которых никому неизвестно кроме вас, как увидеть достоверный код?

Comment: исправил, благодарю

Comment: верните рейтинг моему вопросу, я ж исправил код

Comment: я не ставил вам баллы, кину плюс сейчас

Comment: я на оборот поднял чуть чуть репу

Comment: спасибо, друзья)
я в сердцах не заметил, что миксины у меня там,  уже глаза от этих кодов замылились...

Comment: Попробуйте `.post { align-items: stretch }` и  `.sub-info { grow: 1 }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для класса post можно попробовать установить

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

А для post-info

```
flex: auto;
height: auto
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)
Вылечили)